# Suggest improvements to the following code (left align equations, use sans serif for variables in mathmode)

Tags: math-mode, formatting, chemistry

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage{cancel}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\date{}


\def\eq{\ =\ }
\def\cd{\ \cdot\ }
\def\rarr{\ \Rightarrow\ }

\begin{document}

$
  \mathsf{
    E \eq
      \Delta T\ 
      (m \cd c)
  }\\
$

$
\displaystyle
  \mathsf{
    \frac{
      E
    }{
      m \cd c 
    } \eq
    \Delta T\ 
      \frac{
        \cancel{\mathsf{m}}
        \cd
        \cancel{\mathsf{c}}
      }{
        \cancel{\mathsf{m}}
        \cd
        \cancel{\mathsf{c}}
      }
  }\rarr
  \mathsf{
    \Delta T \eq
      \frac{
        E
      }{
        m \cd c
      }
  }
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What improvement you expect? Are your equation in text (as follows from MWE) or can be present as display math formulas?

Comment: note as you deleted the earlier version I can't reply there. My earlier comment was mostly about `\def\eq{\ =\ }` (not `\mathsf`) this is over-riding the math spacing specifed for = and adding a textual interword space. `\cd` and `\rarr` similar. also ending a paragraph `\\$` produces `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 17--24`  and bad output

Comment: Is one of your objectives to use a sans-serif font for all math material? Please advise.

Comment: yes @mico that's what I want

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I unfairly went off on you that's why I deleted it. I have `eq` as when you wrap everything in `\mathsf` you have to manually space operators

Comment: @Nickotine no, mathsf does not affect `=`.  (you can delete comments without deleting the question:-)

Comment: it does seem to for me in $..$ mode. I write this code on my phone which is why you'll see I take so many new lines.

Comment: yes apologies for yesterday @DavidCarlisle the answer below is good however it is a slightly different version of sans serif I made some edits and added a picture and thank you for `displaystyle`

Comment: I think it might be italicised sans serif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to employ a sans-serif math font that uses slanted rather than upright letters. I therefore suggest you load the [arev](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arev) font package.

I also have reason to believe that a secondary formatting objective of yours is to place displayed equations at the left-hand edge of the text block, rather than centering them horizontally. This objective may be attained by (a) loading the `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) package with the option `fleqn` and (b) issuing the instruction `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} % align displayed equations at left-hand margin

\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{arev} % sans-serif text and math fonts

\newcommand\rarr{\quad\Rightarrow\quad} 

\begin{document}

\noindent
$ E = \Delta T \,(m \cdot c) $

\[
\frac{E}{m \cdot c} =
\Delta T \,
\frac{ \cancel{m}\cdot\cancel{c} }{ \cancel{m}\cdot\cancel{c} }
\rarr
\Delta T =\frac{E}{m \cdot c}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way I can get upright sans-serif instead? Yes thank you for the left aligned equation suggestion I needed that.

Comment: @Nickotine - An important reason for using slanted letters in math mode for variables is that this makes it possible to make the outputs of `\log`, `\det`, `\sin`, `\tan`, etc -- which use upright letters by common convention -- really stand out, greatly improving the overall legibility of the math material. Why throw away this great typographic/stylistic device?

Comment: alright thanks, I'll be using those so I'll take your advice.

Comment: about `rarr` and why I was putting operators in spaced variables, was because I thought in `\mathsf` operators didn't space properly, but I tested and looks like my eyes were playing tricks on me. Much appreciated you done everything I needed despite me not even mentioning it. Apologies for yesterday and the other times where I've been combative you both could've just decided not to help me after that, had nothing but good info from you and @DavidCarlisle. I am doing `S...\\$` then `$\displaystyle...$` as`\[...\]`gives it's own kind of newlines, thanks for `\noindent` I really needed that.

Comment: also is there an advantage doing`\newcommand\name{}` over `\def\name{}`?

Comment: @Nickotine - `\def` is a TeX "primitive", and `\newcommand` is a LaTeX-only command. Pages and pages could be (and have been!) written about the differences between `\def` and `\newcommand`. For (relative) newcomers, I'd say that the main practical difference is safety: `\def` will merrily clobber existing commands (usually with rather ill effects!), whereas `\newcommand` will issue an error message in such cases.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm a fan of using things which avoid problems before they even have a chance to manifest

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to be totally sure from the example, but it seems you want an all sanserif document. That is a 'visual' effect which is different from applying `\mathsf` to everything (as the latter is meant for more 'semantic' changes *and* means the output is no longer italic). With a standard pdfLaTeX setup, this is easiest to achieve using the `sansmath` package, viz.:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\AtBeginDocument{\sansmath}

\begin{document}

$ E = \Delta T (m \cdot c)$

\[
  \frac{E}{m \cdot c} =
    \Delta T \frac{\cancel{m}\cdot\cancel{c}}{\cancel{m}\cdot\cancel{c}} \Rightarrow
    \Delta T =
      \frac{E}{m \cdot c}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but just curius: OP show equations using upright sans serif fonts. How to achieve this by global settings? Is this possible using `pdfLaTeX` engine?

Comment: @Zarko yes, you could use `mathastext` for instance.

Comment: @Zarko `\everymath{\sf}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you very much. This works fine in in-line math expressions but not in displayed math.

Comment: @Zarko `\everydisplay`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, it doesn't work. I will continue discussion in chat rooms at late evening (now I have some obligations).

Comment: this nearly displays the same however the letters are tilted forwards a bit

Comment: I guess this font is a slightly different version of sans serif

Comment: Is there a way to make math symbols such as `\Rightarrow` -- but also `\sum` and `\int`, say -- employ a sans-serif font shape as well?